# "Converse" of continuity: similar outputs imply similar inputs

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, continuity

What do we call a function satisfying the property below?

> $f:X \to Y$ such that for any $x_1, x_2\in X$
> $$
> \| f(x_1) - f(x_2) \| < \epsilon \quad \implies \quad \|x_1 - x_2 \| < \delta
> $$

This looks a lot like the reverse of continuity, here we are saying that similar enough outputs correspond to similar enough inputs.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that if there exists an inverse function $f^{-1}$ then this is similar to continuity of $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Are $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ fixed, or do you want to have the usual "$\forall \delta > 0 : \exists \epsilon > 0$"-story?

Comment: @gerw In my particular example $\epsilon$ can change. I would be equally happy with either to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider the property
$$
\forall x \in X, \varepsilon > 0: \exists \delta > 0: \forall y \in X : \|f(x)-f(y)\|<\varepsilon \;\Rightarrow\; \|x-y\| < \delta.
$$
It is easy to check that this implies injectivity of $f$. Thus, the function $f \colon X \to D := f(X)$ is bijective.
Moreover, the above condition is now equivalent to the continuity of the corresponding inverse $g \colon D \to X$.